# Magento - Downloadable product link empty

Tags: product, ce-1.7.0.2, downloadable, link

We have a problem with our Magento CE 1.7.0.2 Shop before going live, We do not exactly know when did this one happen. We want to offer digital goods (pictures) as download links from an external host.

Everything worked fine - we did not test the checkout for a month.

Now we have a problem, if a customer buys a digital good, his download link for his picture does not work. It is empty. The hash key in the DB seems ok. In Backend, the purchase was triggered. We suppose the connection between the hash key and the external URL is wrong.

We did 2 things since that but already applied a rollback. We installed SSL certificate and a delete old orders extension.

Can one of these things cause our problem?

Comment: Besides that if i click in the frontend on one of the corrupted links, the frontend and the backend of the shop do not work/work very slow for 1 minute. after the loading of the corrupted hash/product has stopped, the shop works again).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its fault of Google Cloud. Every other hosting company works...

Comment: Hello guys. We found out an error via our logs, after some tests and reinstall of the Magento shop. Following message one gets in in the log: No cURL data returned for rentdim.dehttp://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/path/to/… [0] Could not resolve host: www.rentdim.dehttp Any suggestions how this broken link could appear? What can we try to fix in magento? Which php file? or update cURL? We would be so thankful for every hint. –  dimi